# Localhost webserver denying PUT request

Tags: iis, file-upload, https, libcurl

I have configured a webserver on localhost with https using Microsoft IIS Administration. I am able to browse  directory with files with browsers and Visual Studio using localhost prefixed with https, such as https://localhost/trial etc.

I wish to upload a file to the said directory, ie., trial, using Libcurl to test some features. Unfortunately I'm unable to do so.

Using the same Libcurl example as given on
[Libcurl File Upload](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/ftpupload.html)

-modified for https, the console window tells me that the following has occurred, upon running the code :

> IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
>
> #### HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
>
> The page you are
>   looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb)
>   is being used.

I checked the IIS Administrator and saw that all authorizations are allowed. I suppose the fact that it is flagging a HTTP verb issue rather than HTTPS as I'd enabled and used as URL in code isn't a big thing?

Libcurl uses PUT for uploading files, so should be an allowed verb.

I am quite new to this, so I'm not certain I did something incorrect with the setting up of the webserver, or whether there are security issues or permission issues which are causing a problem here.

Comment: "uses PUT for uploading files, so should be an allowed verb" - *should* ? The error message specifically says that the *verb* (that is `PUT`) was invalid.

Comment: Yes, that is true, though I'm not sure why. All permissions are given from my side through the MS IIS Administrator console. I eve tried giving the permission explicitly, but to no avail. Is there something specific I should be looking out for, maybe firewall, AV, or some IIS setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is impossible to use http put or post a file to a IIS web application's folder without writing server-side code. Otherwise, configure an FTP site on your IIS installation. Then you could use ftp command to upload the file.

If you really need using HTTP put or post to upload the file, you could consider using WebDav.

More details about what is webdev and how to use it, you could refer to below article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-webdav-on-iis

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-7/what39s-new-for-webdav-and-iis-7

Answer (score 0):

1. Try hostname instead of localhost
2. Add a trailing slash (/) for the directory.